# Call loudness adjustment

Tags: twilio

I would like to increase the loudness of the calls at the originating point. The mic on the set is no problem, but the earpiece or speaker at the originating end lacks acceptable volume. The volume thru windows is fine and adjustable, but does not allow communication volume adjustment. This problem is only apparent at the originating end.

Answer (score 0):

Rob from Twilio here.

Thanks for the question on controlling volume of a call.  Sounds from your description of "Windows" that you are accepting a call and answering with [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/client?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) in a Windows-based browser - if I'm incorrect pleased let me know.  There is no API control of the volume of a given participant in a call ([full reference on modifying live calls here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon)).

If the person calling into the Client user is having difficulty hearing, you may want to look at your microphone settings on your machine.  Also make sure that you are using a headset and not your computer's built-in microphone.  More tips on troubleshooting Client sound quality are [available here](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-client/how-do-i-troubleshoot-common-problems-with-twilio-client?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon).

Comment: If this is using the video tag under the hood, why not expose `$('video.twilio')[0].volume = 0.6;` or something like that? It could be part of the Twilio.Connection API. (I just re-read the question; seems that doesn't apply here, but this may help others).